# Is there any way to see a kernel function's code?

Tags: functions, kernel, internals

I was using the extremely useful function `PrintDefinitions` from the GeneralUtilities package and I encountered this:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitionsLocal@System`Private`Arguments
```

[image]

I assume this is c-code or something, but perhaps there is some way to print it?

Comment: No, there isn't.